# Kindle Fire Push Notifications Example App

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

[image]

I am implementing Push Notifications with Amazon SNS and I don't understand why in the Mobile-Hub, under platforms I see "Android", "iOS" but not "Kindle".

How can I download an example project to start building a Kindle Fire App with Push Notifications already configurated like I did with the Android version?

P.S: it's incredible that I need to build an Amazon app to use Push Notifications and I can't use my Android version because Google Play Services are not available with Fire Tablets.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback. 
Sample Kindle Fire projects are not on Mobile Hub's immediate road map but we will make it a point to duly add it to our backlog. 
To unblock yourself, We recommend you use the AWS SDK for Android. 
Please refer to this article for details - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-adm.html 
You can also refer to the sample applications uploaded in this folder for reference code - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/samples/snsmobilepush.zip